# Is is possible to re-integrate a sub-project and re-connect mercurial history?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

A while back, we pulled a number of more stable packages out of our main application into separate mercurial repositories.  We share them in a limited way with some other clients, who access them via artifactory, although these external clients don't generally bother or have a need to stay up to date with our changes.  (They are many months behind and doing fine because it's only a few interfaces that are crossing over.)

It's arguable that splitting into separate repositories has made things less efficient for us in that (a) it's more heavy-weight to make changes to the other jars and we sometimes don't bother and (b) it's harder to peruse the changeset history of a feature that involves changes in two or more repos.

We're considering bringing these back into the main repository, but I'm wondering is there any way now to re-connect the histories when doing so?  Ideally I'd like to be able trace the history of a given code file, progresing through recent changes, changes during the separation phase, and hopefully changes from before we split them apart.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can either pull all separate histories into one repository (hg will complain they're unrelated, but will let you proceed anyway if you insist), and then merge them normally (move them into separate directories in each of their branches, and then merge them in a way files from all branches get placed in a single place), or you can filter the history with convert, export/import and maybe mq, but that will be quite difficult to implement.

Comment: Could you edit to make those processes more concrete?  I'm not sure how to implement them in order to try them out.

Comment: Just do a `hg pull --force` (without `--force` Mercurial will abort with an error `unrelated repository`), then do a couple of `hg mv` in each of the branches if the directory structure doesn't match, and then merge them normally.

Comment: That's a bit hackish, but it will work, and both histories will be accessible from the same repository.